# Функция вывода записей с условием по дате

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

В БД MySql есть столбец 'created_at' с датой и временем[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заносится в БД посредством NOW()

```
$query = "INSERT INTO
 comments
 VALUES (
 NULL,
 :nickname,
 :product,
 :cost,
 :phone,
 :email,
 :sizer,
 :content,
 NOW(),
 1)";
```

Как написать функцию чтобы можно было выводить сумму записей в столбце 'cost' ("SELECT SUM(cost) AS sum_cost FROM comments")в определенном заданном временном диапазоне(день, неделя, месяц, год), всего 4 периода времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант

-последний день

```
SELECT SUM(cost) AS sum_cost FROM comments WHERE 'created_at' >= ( CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
```

-последняя неделя

```
SELECT SUM(cost) AS sum_cost FROM comments WHERE 'created_at' >= ( CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Если нужно от конкретной даты, форматируем дату и сравниваем вместо `CURDATE()`

Comment: Дмитрий, вариант то что надо!
Единственное, помогите еще с реализацией.

До этого пара запросов работала так:
          $query = "SELECT COUNT(id)
          AS sum_id
          FROM comments";
          $com = $pdo->query($query);
          while($comments = $com->fetch()) {
          echo
           "<span>Заказов</span>" . "<br>" . "<span>{$comments['sum_id']}</span>" . "<span> шт.</span>" . "<br>" . "<br>";
         }

Поставил ваш код в строку запроса, выдает ошибку
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\OSPanel\..путь

Comment: попробуйте вместо CURDATE() вставить NOW()

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению

Comment: Дмитрий, я разобрался, запрос должен выглядеть данным образом

"SELECT SUM(cost) AS sum_week FROM comments WHERE created_at >= (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)"

Comment: Вы можете внести правки в ваш код, я отмечу его как правильный, как никак Вы меня навели на решение проблемы.

Comment: супер) Работает? а то я тут уже код с запашком придумывать начал начал)